# UIView with a Dashed line

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, calayer, quartz-2d

**What I have:**

[image]

To create this line, I basically have an `UIView` and I do the following:

```
void setLayerToLineFromAToB(CALayer *layer, CGPoint a, CGPoint b, CGFloat lineWidth)
{
    CGPoint center = { 0.5 * (a.x + b.x), 0.5 * (a.y + b.y) };
    CGFloat length = sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
    CGFloat angle = atan2(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x);

    layer.position = center;
    layer.bounds = (CGRect) { {0, 0}, { length + lineWidth, lineWidth } };
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

**Note: This code was found here on stackoverflow, so if someone can give me the reference to it I would appreciate.**

**What I want:**

[image]

Ok so the "only" thing I need is to create this pattern on the `UIView`. I know I am able to do this using Quartz2D (a simple way to do it can be found [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D)). But I want to do it by manipulating the `CALayer` and not going to to the draw method. Why? Because of the transformation I am making on my `UIView`, I am not able to draw correctly using the `draw` method.

**Edit 1:**

Just to illustrate my problem:

[image]

Normally what you have is `UIView` and then you basically just draw something in it (in this case a simple line). The solution I found to get rid of the "gray" area, was to instead of drawing something, just transform the `UIView` itself. It work well, if you want a fully filled line, the problem comes when you want a dashed one.

Comment: Why not drawing this with Quartz2D on a layer and then transform the layer?!

Comment: What are you saying, is basically draw it on the `draw` method and then apply the transform?

Comment: Yes thats what i meant... So thats like you draw an "image" and then just transform this "image"

Comment: @lukaswelte check my edit to see if what you are saying does make sense.

Comment: Getting rid of grey background? Why not just drawing the line in drawRect and then transforming your uiview will do exact the trick you want to… and this with any shape you did draw on the view before

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Note**: The code from Prince did really help me out, so I will give him +10 for the tips. But in the end, I add to come with my own code. I will also add some context to it, so it can be useful for future readers

---

The final code was like this:

```
-(void)updateLine{

      // Important, otherwise we will be adding multiple sub layers
      if ([[[self layer] sublayers] objectAtIndex:0])
        {
            self.layer.sublayers = nil;
        }

        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [shapeLayer setBounds:self.bounds];
        [shapeLayer setPosition:self.center];
        [shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
        [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [shapeLayer setLineWidth:3.0f];
        [shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
        [shapeLayer setLineDashPattern:
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],nil]];

        // Setup the path
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, beginPoint.center.x, beginPoint.center.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, endPoint.center.x, endPoint.center.y);

        [shapeLayer setPath:path];
        CGPathRelease(path);

        [[self layer] addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

In my case, the beginPoint and endPoint are movable by the user, by using KVO. So when one of them moves:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"position"])
    {
        [self updateLine];
    }
}
```

I did play a lot with Prince's code. I tried on the `draw:` method, which add a thin line between the dashed line (a bit weird...) and I also tried on `initWithFrame:`. By itself his code, without any modifications, would give me this kind of errors on the console:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Answer (score 42):

Check UIBezierPath `setLineDash:count:phase:` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624373-setlinedash?language=objc):

```
- (void)setLineDash:(const CGFloat *)pattern count:(NSInteger)count phase:(CGFloat)phase` method.
```

This allows you to draw dashed lines.

1. First add a `CAShapeLayer`. Add it as sublayer to your `UIView`. It has a `path` property.
2. Now make an object of `UIBezierPath`. Draw the line using `setLineDash`.

**For example:**

```
 UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
 //draw a line
 [path moveToPoint:yourStartPoint]; //add yourStartPoint here
 [path addLineToPoint:yourEndPoint];// add yourEndPoint here
 [path stroke];

 CGFloat dashPattern[] = {2.0f,6.0f,4.0f,2.0f}; //make your pattern here
 [path setLineDash:dashPattern count:4 phase:3];

 UIColor *fill = [UIColor blueColor];
 shapelayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
 shapelayer.strokeColor = fill.CGColor;
 shapelayer.lineWidth = 5.0;
 shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter;
 shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:7], nil];
 shapelayer.lineDashPhase = 3.0f;
 shapelayer.path = path.CGPath;
```

**Note:** This answer provides a hint so you can improvise accordingly to your requirement(s).

Comment: Are you doing that before or after applying the transformation?

Comment: i m not applying transformation. Jack Boy u have created layer like a line. but its actually u have not drawn line

Comment: I am doing this on the `initWithFrame:` method of my `UIView`. I am receiving this kind of errors: `<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0`.

Comment: `float dashPattern[] = {2,6,4,2}` should be `CGFloat dashPattern[] = {2,6,4,2}`

Answer (score 32):

Dash Line in **Swift4  •  Xcode 9**

Crate a CAShapeLayer & use [lineDashPattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521921-linedashpattern)

```
extension UIView {

    func addDashedBorder() {
        //Create a CAShapeLayer
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        // passing an array with the values [2,3] sets a dash pattern that alternates between a 2-user-space-unit-long painted segment and a 3-user-space-unit-long unpainted segment
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [2,3]

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                                CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0)])
        shapeLayer.path = path
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
dashView.addDashedBorder()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: how to make the line with full width?

Comment: Why don't you use just `UIView`

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 2.2**

dropping this in here to save others time..

```
extension UIView {
    func addDashedLine(color: UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()) {
        layer.sublayers?.filter({ $0.name == "DashedTopLine" }).map({ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() })
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        let cgColor = color.CGColor

        let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let frameSize = self.frame.size
        let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)

        shapeLayer.name = "DashedTopLine"
        shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
        shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width / 2, y: frameSize.height / 2)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]

        let path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, self.frame.width, 0)
        shapeLayer.path = path

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: you can use .forEach() instead of map, then the compiler doesn't give a warning of unused result of map.

Answer (score 15):

Here is Swift 3 version of **Alexandre G**'s answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194152/1800489

```
extension UIView {

        func addDashedLine(color: UIColor = .lightGray) {
            layer.sublayers?.filter({ $0.name == "DashedTopLine" }).map({ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() })
            backgroundColor = .clear

            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.name = "DashedTopLine"
            shapeLayer.bounds = bounds
            shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
            shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
            shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]

            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: 0))
            shapeLayer.path = path

            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer has a coordinate problem. The line will be drawn some distance below. And I cannot figure out why and how much distance it increases on Y coordinate.

There's a way to draw a dashed line with correct coordinate:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     CGContextBeginPath(cx);
     CGContextRef cx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetLineWidth(cx, _thickness);
     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cx, _color.CGColor);

     CGFloat dash[] = {_dashedLength,_dashedGap};
     CGContextSetLineDash(cx, 0, dash, 2); // nb "2" == ra count
//    CGContextSetLineCap(cx, kCGLineCapRound);

     CGContextMoveToPoint(cx, 0, _thickness);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(cx, self.bounds.size.width, _thickness);
     CGContextStrokePath(cx);
     CGContextClosePath(cx);
}
```

This answer is from [Draw dotted (not dashed!) line, with IBDesignable in 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018302/draw-dotted-not-dashed-line).
DON'T DON'T DON'T forget to set the background color as white when you want a black dashed line!! By default the view has a black background color, and the line color is also black, so I thought it was a solid line. It cost me half a day to find out. T_T

Comment: This might be too late for you but you can check my comment on @Shaheen Ghiassy answer

Comment: Cost me half an hour T_T, thanks to your warning, it did not cost me more.

Answer (score 6):

First all the credit goes to RuiAAPeres and Prince, I'm just encapsulating their answers into a UIView object that others can drop into their projects and use

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/**
 *  Simple UIView for a dotted line
 */
@interface H3DottedLine : UIView

/**
 *  Set the line's thickness
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat thickness;

/**
 *  Set the line's color
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIColor *color;

/**
 *  Set the length of the dash
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat dashedLength;

/**
 *  Set the gap between dashes
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat dashedGap;

@end




@implementation H3DottedLine

#pragma mark - Object Lifecycle

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Set Default Values
        _thickness = 1.0f;
        _color = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _dashedGap = 1.0f;
        _dashedLength = 5.0f;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // Note, this object draws a straight line. If you wanted the line at an angle you simply need to adjust the start and/or end point here.
    [self updateLineStartingAt:self.frame.origin andEndPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x+self.frame.size.width, self.frame.origin.y)];
}

#pragma mark - Setters

- (void)setThickness:(CGFloat)thickness {
    _thickness = thickness;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color {
    _color = [color copy];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setDashedGap:(CGFloat)dashedGap {
    _dashedGap = dashedGap;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setDashedLength:(CGFloat)dashedLength {
    _dashedLength = dashedLength;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

#pragma mark - Draw Methods

-(void)updateLineStartingAt:(CGPoint)beginPoint andEndPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint {

    // Important, otherwise we will be adding multiple sub layers
    if ([[[self layer] sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]) {
        self.layer.sublayers = nil;
    }

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [shapeLayer setBounds:self.bounds];
    [shapeLayer setPosition:self.center];
    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:self.color.CGColor];
    [shapeLayer setLineWidth:self.thickness];
    [shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
    [shapeLayer setLineDashPattern:@[@(self.dashedLength), @(self.dashedGap)]];

    // Setup the path
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, beginPoint.x, beginPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    [shapeLayer setPath:path];
    CGPathRelease(path);

    [[self layer] addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}

@end
```

Comment: For people who can't make this class work.  Try changing all instances of self.frame to self.bounds and set the [shapeLayer setPosition:self.center] to [shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointZero]

Answer (score 6):

**Update Swift 5** & **UIBezierPath**

For those working with `UIBezierPath` instead of `CAShapeLayer`, here is how to achieve it

```
class MyView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        // >> define the pattern & apply it 
        let dashPattern: [CGFloat] = [4.0, 4.0]
        path.setLineDash(dashPattern, count: dashPattern.count, phase: 0)
        // <<
        path.lineWidth = 1
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
        path.stroke()

    }
}
```

As said many times in this thread, you can play with the `pattern` and the `phase` to achieve a complex dotted line.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5 & Using extension :**

Using the following code, you can draw a dashed line in the middle of your view.

```
extension UIView {
    enum dashedOrientation {
        case horizontal
        case vertical
    }
    
    func makeDashedBorderLine(color: UIColor, strokeLength: NSNumber, gapLength: NSNumber, width: CGFloat, orientation: dashedOrientation) {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [strokeLength, gapLength]
        if orientation == .vertical {
            path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY),
                                    CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY)])
        } else if orientation == .horizontal {
            path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY),
                                    CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY)])
        }
        shapeLayer.path = path
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Calling method :

```
vu1.makeDashedBorderLine(color: .black, strokeLength: 7, gapLength: 5, width: 2, orientation: .horizontal)
```

[image: Horizontal]   [image: Vertical]