# How draw a line between 2 CGPoint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, cgpoint

I have this code

```
CGPoint one = [button center];
CGPoint two = [button center];
```

How draw a line at this points? thanks

**I try this**

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();



CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, one.x, one.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, two.x, two.y);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

**But i have this error:**

```
<Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Yes i tried... I have this error:
<Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways to draw your line.

One way is to create a subclass of `UIView` and override its `drawRect:` method.  This is described in [“The View Drawing Cycle” in the *Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW3).

The other way is to use a `CAShapeLayer`.  There are lots of answers on stackoverflow about using a shape layer.  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702204/77567) for a start.