# Border TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to created border dot line of text field of rounded corner. I  sucessfully created a border of text field but i have some problem of rounded corner of border textfield.I need textfield of rounded corner with dotted line. Here is my code.

```
firstName.layer.borderColor =[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

border = [CAShapeLayer layer];
border.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
border.fillColor = nil;
border.lineDashPattern = @[@4, @2];
border.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:firstName.bounds].CGPath;
border.frame = firstName.bounds;

[firstName.layer addSublayer:border];
```

Comment: "some problem ", please explain more

Comment: post screenshot please...

Comment: @please see Nimit explanation

Comment: Please see my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the solution to remove `gray color` border of `UITextField`.

**Problem**

[image]

**Solution**

[image]

For that you need to use following one line of code `Just change the border style`

> _firstName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;

```
CAShapeLayer *border = [CAShapeLayer layer];
border.strokeColor = [UIColor gray].CGColor;
border.fillColor = nil;
border.lineDashPattern = @[@4, @2];
border.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_firstName.bounds].CGPath;
border.frame = _firstName.bounds;

[_firstName.layer addSublayer:border];

_firstName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

**UPDATE**

**For Rounded corner use following function.**

```
- (void)drawDashedBorderAroundView:(UIView *)v
{
    //border definitions
    CGFloat cornerRadius = 10;
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    NSInteger dashPattern1 = 8;
    NSInteger dashPattern2 = 8;
    UIColor *lineColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    //drawing
    CGRect frame = v.bounds;

    CAShapeLayer *_shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    //creating a path
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    //drawing a border around a view
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, frame.size.height - cornerRadius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, cornerRadius);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, M_PI, -M_PI_2, NO);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, 0);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, -M_PI_2, 0, NO);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - cornerRadius);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, frame.size.width - cornerRadius, frame.size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, M_PI_2, NO);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, cornerRadius, frame.size.height);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, cornerRadius, frame.size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, M_PI_2, M_PI, NO);

    //path is set as the _shapeLayer object's path
    _shapeLayer.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);

    _shapeLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _shapeLayer.frame = frame;
    _shapeLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    [_shapeLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isCircle"];
    _shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _shapeLayer.strokeColor = [lineColor CGColor];
    _shapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth;
    _shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dashPattern1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:dashPattern2], nil];
    _shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;

    //_shapeLayer is added as a sublayer of the view, the border is visible
    [v.layer addSublayer:_shapeLayer];
    v.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}
```

Call this function using below code.

```
_firstName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
[self drawDashedBorderAroundView:_firstName];
```

May this help lot.

Comment: i need border radius background gray color

Comment: I need textfield of rounded corner with dotted line

Comment: my problem is that rounded corner of textfield of gray color with dotted line

Comment: For down voter why downvote my answer and try to delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below coding

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 border = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 border.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:67/255.0f green:37/255.0f blue:83/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
 border.fillColor = nil;
 border.lineDashPattern = @[@4, @2];
 [firstName.layer addSublayer:border];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  border.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:firstName.bounds].CGPath;
  border.frame = firstName.bounds;
}
```

Please have a look at the below sources

[UITextField Dotted Border with Rounded Corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204515/how-to-create-a-dotted-line-with-symmetrical-corners)

[Dotted Line UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679923/dashed-line-border-around-uiview)