# How to add background line in multiline label using NSAttributedString in ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, cashapelayer

I want to add background line in multiline label using NSAttributedString in objective-c as shown in image below[image]

I used following code

```
[yourView.layer setBorderWidth:5.0];
[yourView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DotedImage.png"]] CGColor]];///just add image name and create image with dashed or doted drawing and add here
```

But it doesnt work perfectly and I want to implement appropriate methods how can I acheive that. Using these are not appropriate too [Link1](http://lukagabric.com/cashapelayer-example-round-corners-view-with-dashed-line-border/),[Link2](https://github.com/lukagabric/LBorderView),[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701825/drawing-dashed-line-using-calayer),[Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091916/uiview-with-a-dashed-line/#1209120920022002)

**I was able to solve using following code**

```
NSAttributedString * title =
            [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I implement My test in here"
                                            attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];
            [ self.viewOrderCell.labelItem setAttributedText:title];
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133014/uilabel-with-text-struck-through , I think you meant `Strike`.

Comment: I will check that and reply u next day any way thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may mean Strike,iOS 6.0 and upper , `UILabel` supports `NSAttributedString` and `NSMutableAttributedString`

When use `NSAttributedString`

```
NSAttributedString * title =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your String here"
                                    attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];
[label setAttributedText:title];
```

Definition :

```
/** 
 * Returns an NSAttributedString object initialized with a given string and
 attributes.
 *
 *  @param str : The string for the new attributed string.

 *  @param attrs : The attributes for the new attributed string. For information
 *  about where to find the attribute keys you can include in this dictionary,
 *  see the overview section of this document.
 *
 *  @return
     Returns an NSAttributedString object initialized with the characters of aString and the attributes of attributes. The returned object might be different from the original receiver.

 */
- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)str attributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs;
```

When use `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your String here"];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@2
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
```

Definition :

```
/**
 *
 *  @param name : A string specifying the attribute name. Attribute keys can be
 *  supplied by another framework or can be custom ones you define. For
 *  information about where to find the system-supplied attribute keys, see the
 *  overview section in NSAttributedString Class Reference.  
 *
 *  @param value : The  attribute value associated with name.
 *
 *  @param aRange : The range of characters
 *  to which the specified attribute/value pair applies.
 */
- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)aRange;
```

Then

```
yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString;
```

Comment: Ok i will try to implement that and check it

Comment: Thanks for your effort your code are good too and I have upvote for your effort

Comment: do u have any ideas ab this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158404/how-to-add-check-box-in-custom-table-view-cell

Answer (score 4):

Below code may help to solve your problem.

```
NSString* textValue = @"Pages you view in iOS Multiple lines of text in";
NSMutableAttributedString *strikeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textValue];
[strikeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [strikeString length])];
[descriptionLbl  setAttributedText:strikeString];
descriptionLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: Ok i will try to implement that and check it

Comment: Thanks for your effort and i implemented your code it works awesome

Comment: Sorry dude i accepted next answer since it has work out on mine any way  i have gave upvote for you

Comment: do u have any ideas ab this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049551/accessing-custom-cell-attributes-outside-of-cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *attrDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColorFromRGB(0X2846B3)};

NSMutableAttributedString *title =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:hotleUrl attributes: attrDict];

[title addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0,[title length])];
[urlBttn setAttributedTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Please check it. I think your problem solve with this code.