# How to add vertical line between UITableViewCell IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my project i have to add vertical lines but I don't know how to add  a vertical line . I tried to add it into my `UITableView` but it can't.

[image: Example]

Comment: its better you use imageView into your tableViewCells

Comment: look at this [demo](https://github.com/edekhayser/Timeline)

Comment: I will try to do that. thank for  help :)

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap Instead of Image, it would be better to have UIView having width 1 pixel & background colour Black Or whatever you want (Just not white or clearColor)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get this by using adding UIView to CustomCell like this..

[image]

in TableView Data Source Method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check for first cell & last Cell. if `first` cell then hide `LineUpper` & if `Last` cell Then hide `LineLower`..

That's it..

Hope this would solve your Problem.
:)

Comment: I want to add dashed line , for upper and lower line , and my cell height increase with the automaticdimension. I tried writing dimension . Even tried with the writing custom base class during my research. The problem the dash is not consistent. Please suggest me appropriate way to do so... Thanks

Comment: You just need to draw dashed line in view after that view is loaded... reference this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701825/drawing-dashed-line-using-calayer

Answer (score 1):

you can add uiview in `cellforrowAtindexpath` programatically. If `odd IndexPath` then add `view(line)` below Imageview(bus image) else add view(line)above Imageview. Another answer is also good solution if you want to manage from interface builder.

Hope this will help :)