# Draw dotted (not dashed!) line, with IBDesignable in 2017

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

It's easy to draw a **dashed** line with UIKit. So:

```
CGFloat dashes[] = {4, 2};
[path setLineDash:dashes count:2 phase:0];
[path stroke];
```

[image]

Is there any way way to draw a genuine dotted line?

[image]

Comment: here's a fantastic way to draw diagonal lines!  :)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228178/294884

Comment: Thanks Fattie, I used with little modification to make dots count as per height of view, let totalDynamicDots = bounds.size.height / CGFloat(3);
let itemLength = fullHeight / totalDynamicDots

Comment: can we have a horizontal version of this  ? @Fattie

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Set the line cap style to round and set the “on” length to a tiny number.

Swift playground example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x:10,y:10))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:290,y:10))
path.lineWidth = 8

let dashes: [CGFloat] = [0.001, path.lineWidth * 2]
path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)
path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width:300, height:20), false, 2)

UIColor.white.setFill()
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(.infinite)

UIColor.black.setStroke()
path.stroke()

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
let view = UIImageView(image: image)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Result:

[image: dots]

---

For objective-C, using the same example class as in the question, simply add

```
CGContextSetLineCap(cx, kCGLineCapRound);
```

before the call to `CGContextStrokePath`, and change the `ra` array values to match my Swift code.

Comment: The key information is in the first (English text) line of my answer.  The rest is gravy.

Comment: I've found setting the on length to `0.01` gives you a circular dot, whereas they are slightly elongated when using `0`.

Comment: I created that image by taking a screen shot (default system-wide shortcut: ⌘⇧4). There's never been a built-in capture facility in Xcode that I know of.

Comment: James P's advice is invaluable. This bug has caused me so much heart-ache and work. Thank you James. I'll create a semi-Answer, so people can see it more clearly.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the bug workaround and to the latest Swift syntax.

Comment: It occurs to me, there's no `.smallestFiniteMagnitude` !

Answer (score 13):

Objective-C version of the Swift example above:

```
UIBezierPath * path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(290.0, 10.0)];
[path setLineWidth:8.0];
CGFloat dashes[] = { path.lineWidth, path.lineWidth * 2 };
[path setLineDash:dashes count:2 phase:0];
[path setLineCapStyle:kCGLineCapRound];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(300, 20), false, 2);
[path stroke];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 12):

Using a UIView extension, compatible with Swift 3.0 the following should work:

```
extension UIView {

    func addDashedBorder(strokeColor: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor

        let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let frameSize = self.frame.size
        let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)

        shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
        shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound

        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [5,5] // adjust to your liking
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: shapeRect.width, height: shapeRect.height), cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

}
```

Then in a function that runs after `viewDidLoad`, like `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, run the `addDashedBorder` function on the view in question:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var someView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someView = UIView()
        someView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

        view.addSubview(someView)

        someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        someView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        someView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        someView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        someView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        someView.addDashedBorder(strokeColor: UIColor.red, lineWidth: 1.0)
    }

}
```

Comment: This creates a dashed line (i.e., rectangles), but how do you create a dotted (i.e., circles) line?

Answer (score 5):

Hello guys this solution worked for me fine. I found somewhere and changed a bit to prevent console warnings.

```
extension UIImage {
    static func drawDottedImage(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 1))
        path.lineWidth = 1.5           
        let dashes: [CGFloat] = [path.lineWidth, path.lineWidth * 5]
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: 2, phase: 0)
        path.lineCapStyle = .butt
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: width, height: height), false, 2)
        color.setStroke()
        path.stroke()

        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: I like this easy way

Answer (score 3):

I work a bit on rob mayoff accepted solution to easily customize the dotted line:

- change the radius of each circle.
- change the number of spaces between 2 circles.
- change the number of patterns to generate.

The function return an UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {

    class func dottedLine(radius radius: CGFloat, space: CGFloat, numberOfPattern: CGFloat) -> UIImage {


        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(radius/2, radius/2))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake((numberOfPattern)*(space+1)*radius, radius/2))
        path.lineWidth = radius

        let dashes: [CGFloat] = [path.lineWidth * 0, path.lineWidth * (space+1)]
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)
        path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake((numberOfPattern)*(space+1)*radius, radius), false, 1)
        UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()
        path.stroke()
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image

    }
}
```

And here is how to get the image:

```
UIImage.dottedLine(radius: 100, space: 2, numberOfPattern: 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, just a very **important gotcha** that James P raised in a comment on the favourite answer:

He wrote:

> I've found setting the on length to **0.01** gives you a circular dot,
>   whereas they are slightly elongated when using 0.

For example,

```
   let dashes: [CGFloat] = [0.001, path.lineWidth * 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.1 you can use below code:

```
context.setLineCap(.round)
```

Have three styles:

```
 /* Line cap styles. */

public enum CGLineCap : Int32 {

    case butt

    case round

    case square
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine with the below code,

```
layer.path = linePath.cgPath
layer.lineWidth = 3
layer.lineDashPattern = [1,layer.lineWidth*2] as [NSNumber]
layer.lineCap = "round"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's maybe too late to answer on that question. but if you agree I would like to share an easy way to resolve that to the developers that will maybe face that problem in the future. so I guess that the easiest solution using @IBDesignable. You need just to create that class

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DottedVertical: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var dotColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var lowerHalfOnly: Bool = false

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // say you want 8 dots, with perfect fenceposting:
        let totalCount = 8 + 8 - 1
        let fullHeight = bounds.size.height
        let width = bounds.size.width
        let itemLength = fullHeight / CGFloat(totalCount)

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let beginFromTop = CGFloat(0.0)
        let top = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: beginFromTop)
        let bottom = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: fullHeight)

        path.move(to: top)
        path.addLine(to: bottom)

        path.lineWidth = width
        //DASHED SIMPLE LINE
        //let dashes: [CGFloat] = [itemLength, itemLength]
        //path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)

        // for ROUNDED dots, simply change to....
        let dashes: [CGFloat] = [0.0, itemLength * 1.1]
        path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)

        dotColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

And then append it to your view in the storyboard like that 
[image]

Once you've done you cold customize the space between the layers from this line `let dashes: [CGFloat] = [0.0, itemLength * 1.1]`  --> Line 39 in the DottedVertical class.
or if you want to customize the width of the layer you need just to edit your line view width from your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Create vertical or horizontal dashed/dotted line using CAShapeLayer and CGMutablePath

```
    func drawDottedLine(dashColor:UIColor,linePattern:[NSNumber] = [2,2],lineWidth:CGFloat = 1, orientation: Orientation = .horizontal, shape: Shape = .line) {
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = dashColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = linePattern 
    if shape == .round {
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    }
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    if orientation == .vertical {
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: lineWidth/2, y: lineWidth/2),
                                CGPoint(x: lineWidth/2, y: self.frame.height)])
    } else {
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: lineWidth/2, y: lineWidth/2),
                                CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: lineWidth/2)])
    }
    shapeLayer.path = path
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented following piece of code to add border with dotted style at bottom of `titleLabel` (`UILabel`) in `viewDidAppear`:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapelayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, titileLabel.frame.size.height-2)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, titileLabel.frame.size.height-2)];
UIColor *fill = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.80f green:0.80f blue:0.80f alpha:1.00f];
shapelayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
shapelayer.strokeColor = fill.CGColor;
shapelayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3 ], nil];
shapelayer.path = path.CGPath;

[titileLabel.layer addSublayer:shapelayer];
```

Refrence : https://gist.github.com/kaiix/4070967

Comment: this is producing squares, not circles, when I use your code.

Comment: try changing moveToPoint, addLineToPoint,linewidth and lineDashPattern values as per your requirement