# How to fill a UIView with an alternating stripe pattern programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, core-graphics, cgcontext

I can achieve an alternating stripe pattern fill using an image with `UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "pattern.png"))`.

However, how can I achieve an alternating stripe pattern fill drawing it programmatically with some simple compact code?

Here are two examples I'd like to achieve.

**Question**

> **Using code, how do I fill a `UIView` with different alternating color stripes using Swift?**
>
> (1) a two color alternating pattern running top to bottom (90
>   degrees)?
>
> (2) a three color alternating pattern running top left to bottom right
>   (45 degrees)?

[image]

Comment: Down vote? I've asked a clear pointed question.

Comment: More down votes without an explanation in the comments of why? Oh the joys of the internet. Have a great day mystery visitors :-)

Comment: Anyone who downvoted this is totally bizarre - it must have just been an accident.

Comment: Appreciate it, @Fattie!

Comment: BTW another excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35820837/294884

Comment: @Fattie thanks, good to learn another approach.

Comment: And here's the **REALLY SIMPLE** way to do it ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228178/294884

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filling a view with a stripe pattern with two, three or more color stripes with adjustable stripe widths and rotation can be achieved with the below code. This code gives a three colour stripe pattern shown in the example image below.

**Steps:**

> 1. Add the below code to ViewController.swift
> 2. Add a UIView to Storyboard.
> 3. Add new alignment contstraints to the UIView on the Storyboard; Horizontally in Container = 0, Vertically in Container = 0.
> 4. In the Identity Inspector, set the UIView custom class to 'colorStripesView'.
> 5. Connect the UIView on the Storyboard to the viewPattern IBOutlet in the code.

**Code:**

```
    ////   ViewController.swift

    //// 1. Add the below code to ViewController.swift
    //// 2. Add a UIView to Storyboard.
    //// 3. Add new alignment contstraints to the UIView on the Storyboard; Horizontally in Container = 0, Vertically in Container = 0.
    //// 4. In the Identity Inspector, set the UIView custom class to 'colorStripesView'.
    //// 5. Connect the UIView on the Storyboard to the viewPattern IBOutlet in the code.

    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var viewPattern: UIView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //// Extend width and height constraints by factor of 2 for viewPattern rotation.
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewPattern, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: (max(view.bounds.height, view.bounds.width)*2))
            viewPattern.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewPattern, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: (max(view.bounds.height, view.bounds.width)*2))
            viewPattern.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

            //// Rotate pattern 0 degrees - vertical.
            //viewPattern.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI*0/180))
            //// Rotate pattern 45 degrees - diagonal top right to bottom left.
            //viewPattern.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI*45/180))
            //// Rotate pattern 90 degrees - horizontal.
            //viewPattern.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI*90/180))
            //// Rotate pattern 135 degrees - diagonal top left to bottom right.
            viewPattern.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI*135/180))

            //// Set view color
            viewPattern.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
    }

    class colorStripesView: UIView {
        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            //// Set pattern tile colors width and height; adjust the color width to adjust pattern.
            let color1 = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 10/255, alpha: 1.0)
            let color1Width: CGFloat = 10
            let color1Height: CGFloat = 10

            let color2 = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0)
            let color2Width: CGFloat = 10
            let color2Height: CGFloat = 10

            let color3 = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 128/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0)
            let color3Width: CGFloat = 10
            let color3Height: CGFloat = 10

            //// Set pattern tile orientation vertical.
            let patternWidth: CGFloat = (color1Width + color2Width + color3Width)
            let patternHeight: CGFloat = min(color1Height, color2Height, color3Height)

            //// Set pattern tile size.
            let patternSize = CGSize(width: patternWidth, height: patternHeight)

            //// Draw pattern tile
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(patternSize, false, 0.0)

            let color1Path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: color1Width, height: color1Height))
            color1.setFill()
            color1Path.fill()

            let color2Path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: color1Width, y: 0, width: color2Width, height: color2Height))
            color2.setFill()
            color2Path.fill()

            let color3Path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: color1Width + color2Width, y: 0, width: color3Width, height: color3Height))
            color3.setFill()
            color3Path.fill()

            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            //// Draw pattern in view
            UIColor(patternImage: image).setFill()
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        }
    }
```

**Simulator:**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For my application it was more helpful and performant to create a pattern `UIColor` that can be used as a background color.

Once I add this as an extension to `UIColor` I can easily put this anywhere in my code and it will always fill perfectly, even as views rotate, shrink and grow!

You use it like this:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.patternStripes()
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.patternStripes(color2: .darkGray)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.patternStripes(color2: .darkGray, barThickness: 25.0)
```

and get this beauty:

[image: Square showing diagonal stripe pattern]

Here is an extension to UIColor:

```
extension UIColor {
    
    /// make a diagonal striped pattern
    func patternStripes(color2: UIColor = .white, barThickness t: CGFloat = 25.0) -> UIColor {
        let dim: CGFloat = t * 2.0 * sqrt(2.0)

        let img = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: .init(width: dim, height: dim)).image { context in

            // rotate the context and shift up
            context.cgContext.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 4.0)
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -2.0 * t)

            let bars: [(UIColor,UIBezierPath)] = [
                (self,  UIBezierPath(rect: .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: dim * 2.0, height: t))),
                (color2,UIBezierPath(rect: .init(x: 0.0, y: t, width: dim * 2.0, height: t)))
            ]

            bars.forEach {  $0.0.setFill(); $0.1.fill() }
            
            // move down and paint again
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: 2.0 * t)
            bars.forEach {  $0.0.setFill(); $0.1.fill() }
        }
        
        return UIColor(patternImage: img)
    }
}
```

Basically, I am creating a temporary drawing space for one little rectangle to paint. I paint it with a pattern that will match seamlessly on all sides when repeated. Then I snap an image of this and tell `UIColor` to use it as a pattern.

The trick I that you have to make your pattern image big enough to paint each bar two times. That turns out to be bar thickness * 2 * sqrt(2).

I know I could get beaten up a little about style. Here are my thoughts:

1. I used one letter variables like `t`, which is not very descriptive. My defense: I think it makes the equations more readable and feel like it's okay when it's limited to only the next few lines.
2. Tuples. Same as #1
3. Using decimals ( `4.0` instead of just `4`). I would prefer to *not* use the decimals but I have found better compile times with the decimal. On bigger projects it can make a huge difference. I will also admit that it may not read as pretty but being less ambiguous about type can even be helpful to humans.

**3 Colors:**
I just realized that the original question was asking for 3 colors, so here is a version for that...

First, the math:

[image]

Updated code:

```
extension UIColor {
    
    /// make a diagonal striped pattern
    func pattern3Stripes(color2: UIColor, color3: UIColor, barThickness t: CGFloat = 25.0) -> UIColor {
        let sqrt2: CGFloat = sqrt(2.0)
        let dim: CGFloat = t * 3.0 * sqrt2
        let size: CGSize = .init(width: dim, height: dim)
        
        let img = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { context in
            
            // rotate the context and shift up
            context.cgContext.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 4.0)
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -3.0 * t)
            
            let bars: [(UIColor,UIBezierPath)] = [
                (self,  UIBezierPath(rect: .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: dim * sqrt2, height: t))),
                (color2,UIBezierPath(rect: .init(x: 0.0, y: t, width: dim * sqrt2, height: t))),
                (color3,UIBezierPath(rect: .init(x: 0.0, y: 2.0 * t, width: dim * sqrt2, height: t)))
            ]
            
            bars.forEach {  $0.0.setFill(); $0.1.fill() }
            
            // move down and paint again
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: 3.0 * t)
            bars.forEach {  $0.0.setFill(); $0.1.fill() }
        }
        
        return UIColor(patternImage: img)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.pattern3Stripes(color2: .white, color3: .red, barThickness: 25.0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't think we need the negative zeros, regular zeros should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, @ACLima, I agree. I don't know why I did that... probably had some other values originally.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

You might be able to draw your stripes using a Core Image filter, or you could create a custom subclass of UIImage and implement the `drawRect` method.

### EDIT

#### Using a `CIFilter`:

I have a sample project called [**CIFilterTest**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/CIFilterTest) (link) on Github that lets you try out all different kinds of Core Image Filters. It interrogates the system for a list of available filters and then tries to build a UI for entering the different settings for each filter. It doesn't support some of the more special-purpose inputs, but it will let you try out the `CIStripesGenerator`, which is the filter that will create alternating stripes for you. The program is written in Objective-C but it should give you the general idea. Note that it looks like the `CIStripesGenerator` filter will only generate stripes in 2 alternating colors, so you wouldn't be able to use it for your 3-color case.

#### Using `drawRect`:

In `drawRect` you'd create a series of UIBezierPaths and fill them with alternating colors. For the vertical stripes you could use the simple `bezierPathWithRect:` init method. For the diagonal lines you'd either need to create the horizontal stripes using `moveToPoint` & `lineToPoint`, or apply a rotation transform to rectangle paths.

### EDIT #2:

Here is a sample class that draws 2 colored rectangles inside itself:

```
class StripedView: UIView {
  
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
      
      //Create a rect for the lefthand stripe
      var rect = CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 10)
      rect.size.width /= 2
      var bezier = UIBezierPath(rect: rect) //Create a bezier for the left stripe
      
      //Set the fill color to blue for the first rect
      UIColor.blueColor().setFill()
      bezier.fill()
      
      //Shift the rect over for the righthand stripe
      rect.origin.x = rect.size.width
      bezier = UIBezierPath(rect: rect) //Create a bezier for the right stripe
      
      UIColor.redColor().setFill()
      bezier.fill()
  }
}
```

You'll need to expand on the code above to create a series of repeating stripes rather than 2 rectangles, and to use 3 rather than 2 colors.

Rotating the stripes 45 degrees is more complicated. Probably the simplest way to do that would be to create diagonal stripes by mapping out the corners of each stripe along the borders of the view and then creating a `UIBezierPath` for each stripe using `moveToPoint` and `lineToPoint` calls. That's beyond the scope of a forum post.

Comment: Thanks, but that’s not it. This just creates two thick lines in a view and not a stripe pattern.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. I gave you code that shows you how to draw rectangular blocks in multiple colors in a custom subclass of UIView by implementing the drawRect method. You should be able to start from that code and implement what you need. It looks like somebody else did you work for you though.

Comment: I did my own original work and tried writing a model answer for Stackoverflow so anyone could replicate it in their own project. It's not perfect, but it is constructive and the result will work well for the interim.