# Draw on UIView or GLKView?

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es, glkview

I need to draw a separator line with some dots on it. I have decided I will do this using the draw method, as opposed to including images of the separator. I will do this for performance and for customisability, as the separator changes sometimes.

Now I have looked into the `draw()` method on `UIView` and I have noticed that Apple suggests using `GLKView` when drawing using OpenGL.

For a simple separator, won't it be too much of a hassle to call OpenGL? Or is the OpenGL overhead negligible? When would I want to use the native UIKit `draw()` then?

FYI I don't know either method, but want to learn both methods, so don't reply "what you know best". I am simply asking about performance.

Comment: What do you want to draw?

Comment: are you going to use it for an iOS normal app or an iOS game?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri an iOS app, not a game.

Comment: @User511 A line with some dots on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL uses GPU instead of CPU for computation. If you are making something like a gaming app, then you can think of using OpenGL. I believe you want to draw a line in an iOS App. For that you can either use `drawRect` method in UIView or create a `shapeLayer` and add it as a sublayer.

The following examples will show you:

```
CAShapeLayer *simpleLine = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 80)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 80)];
simpleLine.lineWidth = 1.0;
simpleLine.path = path.CGPath;
simpleLine.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:simpleLine];
```

For using `drawRect`, you are supposed to do this inside a Custom UIView as opposed to the above method.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 80)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 80)];
    path.lineWidth = 1.0;
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

If your separator parameters changes and if you are making an app, it's better to use `drawRect` method. You can call this method anytime by using `[CustomUIView setNeedsDisplay:YES]`

**Edit**

What you're asking for is circle over line. You can do that by drawing `UIBezierPath` for `line` first and then add `UIBezierPath` for `circle` later.

Comment: You suggest using the draw method in UIView as opposed to GLKView for a simple line?

Comment: GLKView uses openGL. The Open Graphics Library (OpenGL) is used for visualizing 2D and 3D data. It is a multipurpose open-standard graphics library that supports applications for 2D and 3D digital content creation, mechanical and architectural design, virtual prototyping, flight simulation, video games, and more. If you are going to create a simple app, and for a simple line in that, I don't see a need for using GPU. If it is a game, then it's different

Comment: How would I draw a circle on this line?

Comment: Do you want a dotted line? something like `........`. If that's what you want, then it already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018302/draw-dotted-not-dashed-line

Comment: No, it's something like this: http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/dots-line.png

Answer (score 0):

**Normal Line**

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

**Dotted Line**

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = @[@4, @2];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```