# Dashed horizontal line using IBDesignable

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation

So i came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26018302/8192960) question, and i want to achieve this to draw a horizontal line with the same approach using `@IBDesignable`.

I have tried to play around inside the class, but no result.

```
@IBDesignable class DottedVertical: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var dotColor: UIColor = UIColor.etc
    @IBInspectable var lowerHalfOnly: Bool = false

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // say you want 8 dots, with perfect fenceposting:
        let totalCount = 8 + 8 - 1
        let fullHeight = bounds.size.height
        let width = bounds.size.width
        let itemLength = fullHeight / CGFloat(totalCount)

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let beginFromTop = CGFloat(0.0)
        let top = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: beginFromTop)
        let bottom = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: fullHeight)

        path.move(to: top)
        path.addLine(to: bottom)

        path.lineWidth = width

        let dashes: [CGFloat] = [itemLength, itemLength]
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)

        // for ROUNDED dots, simply change to....
        //let dashes: [CGFloat] = [0.0, itemLength * 2.0]
        //path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round

        dotColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve as below,

```
@IBDesignable class DottedHorizontal: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var dotColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var lowerHalfOnly: Bool = false

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let fullHeight = bounds.size.height
        let width = bounds.size.width

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: fullHeight/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: fullHeight/2))

        path.lineWidth = 5

        let dashes: [CGFloat] = [4, 2]
        path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)

        dotColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: but the height isn't the full height of the View

Comment: Change `lineWidth = 5` to `lineWidth = fullHeight`