# Change Dashed Line Thickness On IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092002/3423468) to draw dashed line on `uiview`:

```
 UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
 //draw a line
 [path moveToPoint:yourStartPoint]; //add yourStartPoint here
 [path addLineToPoint:yourEndPoint];// add yourEndPoint here
 [path stroke];

 float dashPattern[] = {1,1,1,1}; //make your pattern here
 [path setLineDash:dashPattern count:4 phase:0];

 UIColor *fill = [UIColor blueColor];
 shapelayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
 shapelayer.strokeColor = fill.CGColor;
 shapelayer.lineWidth = 7.0;
 shapelayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter;
 shapelayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10], nil];
 shapelayer.lineDashPhase = 3.0f;
 shapelayer.path = path.CGPath;
```

it works, but problem is that even though I set my `uiview` height 1, the line I get is quite thick.
[image]

is it possible to make it thinner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the thickness of the line at this part of your code:

```
shapelayer.lineWidth = 7.0;
```

Change the `7.0` to whatever thickness you would like your line to have.

Comment: WTF :/ why the hell does the property named lineWIDTH change the HEIGHT of it? :(
anyway, thanks a lot :|

Comment: because the `line` have width not height, englishically. ;)

Comment: 'lineThickness' would make sense

Comment: @Mr.Bista if line is 1D then yes, but this line doesn't look like one; anyway, as @RJR said `lineThickness` would make much more sense.

Comment: I think term Thickness is used for 3D Object, else it will be Width. **Source:** Google `Thick vs Width -> Images`