# How to add dashed line inside view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, drawrect

How can I add a dashed line inside UIView?

My code:

```
let  path = UIBezierPath()

let  p0 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(view.bounds),
                              CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds))
path.moveToPoint(p0)

let  p1 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(view.bounds),
                              CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds))
path.addLineToPoint(p1)

let  dashes: [ CGFloat ] = [ 16.0, 32.0 ]
path.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0.0)

path.lineWidth = 8.0
path.lineCapStyle = .Butt
UIColor.magentaColor().set()
path.stroke()
view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

But it does not display anything.

I am getting this in the log:

> CGContextSetLineDash: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Comment: can you add a visual what view you want to create.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091916/uiview-with-a-dashed-line

Comment: Are you calling this inside the `drawRect:` function? Make sure you do that, and then remove `view.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: Swift 2...  Yuck...  It's obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
let rect = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize.init(width: 180, height: 180))//Set Height width as you want
let layer = CAShapeLayer.init()
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 8)
layer.path = path.cgPath;
layer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 205/255, green: 207/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor; // Set Dashed line Color
layer.lineDashPattern = [7,7]; // Here you set line length
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor;
layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor;
self.newView.layer.addSublayer(layer);
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Omit the `.init`s for more concise code, e.g.: `let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), size: CGSize(width:180, height:180))`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to add dashed line to your parent view.

```
for index in 0 ..< 10 {
  let frame : CGRect = CGRectMake(index*10,200,2,30)
  var subview : UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
  testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
  testView.alpha=1.0
  self.view.addSubview(testView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I created a box and gave a height of e.g. 1 and added a dashed **CAShapeLayer**:

```
let line = CAShapeLayer()

let rect = CGRect(x: /*X position*/, y: /*Y position */, width: /*X width of line*/, height: /*height of line*/)

line.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, cornerRadius:0).cgPath
line.frame = self.bounds
line.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
line.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
line.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]
view.layer.addSublayer(line)
```

Hope that helps!!